# ms-access selecting the problematic data

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

i have data that looks like this:

```
alex hub
liza fds
harry ok
lena yyy
liza ok
```

i would like a sql statement that will give me this:

```
alex hub
lena yyy
```

i need to return all the column1's where there is no correspending `"ok"` for column2

please note that if there is just ONE `"ok"` that is enough to not return that data

thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sql query:

```
select Col1, Col2 from MyTable
where Col1 not in (
    select Col1 
    from MyTable 
    where Col2 = 'ok'
)
```

Comment: NOT IN is not reliably optimized with Jet/ACE -- it won't be guaranteed to use the indexes on both sides of the comparison. That can make it incredibly slow with any large amount of data. I'd do this instead with a subselect JOIN'ed to the main table, which always uses the indexes in Jet/ACE.

Comment: You really need to have a JOIN to a subquery written out for you? See @HansUp's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The LEFT JOIN to a subquery of "ok" rows and the **WHERE (((t2.column1) Is Null))** return only those column1 values which have no row with "ok" as column2.

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2
FROM Table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN [
        SELECT column1, column2
        FROM Table1 WHERE column2 = "ok"]. AS t2
    ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
WHERE (((t2.column1) Is Null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the most straightforward way to do this is simply:

```
SELECT people.personname, people.status
FROM people
WHERE [people]![status]<>'ok';
```

Sometimes it is useful to go through the exercise of implementing your answer in Access. I discovered that I can't use `name` as a columname, and there is a third record that meets the condition.

```
personname  status
==========  ======
alex        hub
liza        fds
lena        yyy
```

Comment: The OP wanted liza excluded because of the row with "liza ok".